# How to use pgbench?

Tags: postgresql, benchmarking, psql, pgbench

I have a table on pgadmin4 which consist of 100.000 lines and 23 columns.I need to benchmark postgresql on this specific table using pgbench,but i cant understand what parameters should i use.The database name is desdb and table called test.

Comment: Either you use `pgbench`'s default tests, which are created by `pgbench`, or you have to write your own scripts.

Answer (score 1):

PgAdmin4 is not a database server, it is a client.  You don't have tables "on" pgadmin4, pgadmin4 is just one way of accessing tables which are on an actual server.

You don't benchmark tables, you benchmark queries.  Knowing nothing about the table other than its name, all I could propose for a query is something like:

```
select * from test
```

Or

```
select count(*) from test
```

You could put that in a file `test.sql`, then run:

```
pgbench -n -f test.sql -T60 -P5 desdb
```

If you are like me and don't like littering your filesystem with bunches of tiny files with contents of no particular interest and you if use the bash shell, you could not create a test.sql file and instead make it dynamic:

```
pgbench -n -f <(echo 'select * from test') -T60 -P5 desdb
```

Whether that is a meaningful query to be benchmarking, I don't know.  Do you care about how fast you can read (and then throw away) all columns for all rows in the table?

Comment: Thank you!Yes,the job i have to do is to create a table and test postgresql and timescaledb which one of them is faster.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer details regarding pgbench from : https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/tuning-postgresql-with-pgbench.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).